# Alternatives to professional data rescue

Tags: mount, data-recovery

I have a broken external hard drive that spins, but won't come up in `/dev`, and thus I can't mount it and run `ddrescue` on it. (I've rescued many drives before using this method.)

When the drive doesn't come up in `/dev`, is there anything I can do except turn the drive over to professionals and pay a high fee to have the data retrieved?

Professional data retrieval often costs $500+, so I would be willing to buy hardware/software for less if it recovered the data and didn't require soldiering or advanced forensics on my side.

Comment: Unfortunately data recovery of this type is better off left to a professional, especially if you absolutely need the data. It is not worth the risk of you trying and failing and spoiling a professionals chance of getting it for you.

Answer (score 2):

**The reason why you leave this to professionals is because they do this all the time for a living, and if you mess up it will only cost more to recover it**.

Lets assume you ignore everyone's warning because you like danger.

In order to even open a hard drive you need a completely dust free sealed environment as the tiniest spec of dust could make professional recovery even more expensive.  If you bought and identical model hard drive, you might be able to switch the circuit board, and/or platters depending on what is broken.  Replacing the circuit board is easier, because you don't have to open the drive.  **Even then unique differences in the drive might prevent this from working.**

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous comments and answer, if the data is important leave it to the professionals. Anything you attempt to do that is unsuccessful will make the professional option more expensive.

---

On the other hand, if you want to have fun attempting to retrieve data there are two methods I've used with a *low success rate*. Just a fair warning: the distant past (all on IDE drives) and both less than 10% success rate. I used to work in PC repair and had access to many bad drives.

First, if the drive isn't showing up in the BIOS or OS but it spins, it may just be an issue with the controller board. Replace the board with one from an identical drive.

Second, if the drive shows up but can't be read, particularly if it can be read for a short time then stops; put it in the freezer. Hopefully it will read long enough to get your data off before it stops working.

I've never had any luck retrieving data from a dead drive by opening it. **There is no reason to open it** except to play around with it. There are some cool magnets in there and the platters make good drink coaster conversation starters.

Answer (score 0):

If data can't be recovered by software data recovery programs or you can't even get a system to recognize the drive (I've occasionally encountered cases where some systems wouldn't recognize a drive, but another would, so you could try attaching the drive to another system), you can find lots of videos on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com) where people offer tutorials on repairing hard drives, if you search on "hard drive repair", "drive won't mount", etc., where people open up a drive to attempt to get it working again. E.g., [Hard Drive Repair And Data Recovery On 500GB Hard Disk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Flom4k7lPUo) or [How to recover data from a hard drive (stuck heads: buzzing, clicking, etc)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5Y7BniaRXg). I would only suggest trying such methods yourself if you need to recover the data by any feasible means, but can't afford or justify the cost for a professional recovery service, since it is possible a professional recovery service could recover the data from the drive in its current state, but will be unable to do so after a failed attempt at self-repair.

If the loss of the data will be a tremendous impact to you, the professional recovery option is the best course. By "professional recovery service", I mean a company that specializes in recovering data from failed hard drives, so has a "[clean room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleanroom)" and specialized equipment, not a local computer repair shop. For such a service, expect to pay $500 to $1,000. Though, if the problem is with the controller board, you can find some services that offer a much lower cost to replace that board, e.g., [Outsource Data Recovery](http://outsourcedatarecovery.com) charges $60 for [printed circuit board (PCB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board) replacement; they have a video on their site with tips on how to do so yourself, if you want to attempt replacement of the controller board. That company also offers a no-interest financing option, if you desperately need the data, but can't afford to pay the full cost all at once - I haven't used their service personally, but that is mentioned in their [FAQ](http://outsourcedatarecovery.com).